# how to set dafault value for custom field in configurable product with magento 1.9

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

i'm working with magento 1.9.0.1.I have a series of products with custom options of type radio. However I cannot set from the setup of the product the default state of that particular option.

I need at least one of the checkboxes (options) to be checked by default as the user enters the product page / adds to cart from category page.

Is this doable from the Magento administration or will it require some extra development (if so how this can be done)?

Answer (score 0):

make the Custom option required this will make the customer to select any of the options provided by you. Making the option Required - Yes. wont make the customer continue till he selects the check boxes.